# CSS - background-color not working in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I am using bootstrap on my site and have a few buttons with `class="btn btn-dark"`.

I have changed the color in my own css.

First I tried hex values `.btn-dark{background-color:#343a40;border-color:#343a40;}`

Then I tried rgba values `.btn-dark{background-color:rgba(52,58,64,1);border-color:rgba(52,58,64,1)}`

Then after a bit of research I seen that it may be something to do with transparency in safari so added `opacity:1;` but no joy.

It's fine in chrome, firefox, edge, uc browser and opera.

But in safari they look like this:
[image]

I am a windows user so trying to test this in the last version of safari available for windows (5.1.7) so I can't do much.

Comment: Well you've got to have some pretty specific reasons for your website to run perfectly on a 2012 browser... If you don't care that much about it, maybe you should consider getting your hands on some proper testing tools instead to see if it runs fine on the latest safari version or not.

Comment: @ThibautMaurice i don't need it to be that backwards compatible i was just saying as a windows user i can't really play around with it in the console like i normally would to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

First of clear your cashes than, use background:#343a40; like this... I think so your problem will be solved

Comment: Try this: background-color:#343a40 !important;border-color:#343a40 !important;

Comment: or rename a class, you are styling on a bootstrap class that is why you are facing this issue